# Boolean use for decision making

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-logic

Basically I want to do a method that is used to make decision, which when the `HitshipPercentage` is less than 50 and the shots is not equal to zero, it will use the method public space `fire()`. I am not sure how to use the boolean  in the correct way.

```
public Space fire()
{
 System.out.println("Hi");
}

     public boolean hitRateAnalysis()
 {

     if (HitShipPercentage < 50 && Shots!=0) 

      return true;

     else{
     return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `fire(..)` is suposed to return a `Space`...

Comment: `if (hitRateAnalysis()) { fire(); }` But, the method name makes it unclear what the return value means. What does analysis result of `true` mean? Choose a better method name that correctly reflects the true/false nature of the result, and what the two values mean, e.g. `shouldFire()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your fire() is wrong and will cause a compilation error, you have to return an instance of Space. Either change the return type of the method to void or return an instance of the Space class.

This will call the fire method correctly:

```
public boolean hitRateAnalysis() {
   if (HitShipPercentage < 50 && Shots != 0){
      fire();
      return true;
    }
   return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few errors in it, the `fire()` method is of type `Space` which means it's supposed to return a `Space`.  I don't think this is what you want, my guess is fire isn't supposed to return anything in which case it should be `void`.

```
public void fire() {
    System.out.println("Hi");
}

public boolean hitRateAnalysis() {
    if (HitShipPercentage < 50 && Shots!=0)  {
        fire();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```